# Get $order in wp_head

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to get the purchased products on the `order-received` page to do a remarketing `dataLayer`. The script must go in the `<head>` section of the html code. How can I get the `$order` to use it in the `<head>` section?

I can get the `$order_id` in `woocommerce_thankyou` but not in `wp_head`

```
function tracking_thank_you_page( $order_id ) {
?>
    <script>
        console.log( 'order_id: <?php echo $order_id; ?>' );
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'tracking_thank_you_page' );
```

I have the `$order_id` with the code above.

```
function tracking_in_head( $order_id ) {
?>
    <script>
        console.log( 'order_id: <?php echo $order_id; ?>' );
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'tracking_in_head' );
```

I don't have access to the `$order_id` in the `wp_head`

UPDATE:
After Hectors useful reply I edited my code. It creates the javascript `dataLayer` with the products SKU:

```
function tracking_in_head() {
    $product_skus = '';
    global $wp_query;
    if( !empty( $wp_query->query_vars[ 'order-received' ] ) ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $wp_query->query_vars[ 'order-received' ] );
        $items = $order->get_items();
        echo "<script>
            dataLayer = [];
            dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'purchase',
                ";
                if( !empty( $items ) ) {
                    echo "'items': [";
                        foreach( $items as $item ) {
                            $product = wc_get_product( $item[ 'product_id' ] );
                            echo "{
                                'id': '" . $product->get_sku() . "',
                                'google_business_vertical': 'retail'
                            },";
                        }
                    echo "]";
                }
            echo "});
        </script>";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'tracking_in_head' );
```

Is there anything to improve on this code?

Comment: What do you expect as an improvement? Isn't it working?

Comment: It does work perfectly. I thought maybe there is a cleaner way to get the ordered items SKU or to transform the data into the javascript datalayer prettier.

Comment: Your codes looks fine. Especially if it works, then it is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check both hooks.
The `woocommerce_thankyou` hook is added on [line 80 of thankyou.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/thankyou.php#L80) file.
The hook is getting `$order->get_id()` as an argument. So, you have access to the order ID in when you hook to `woocommerce_thankyou` in your first example.

But the `wp_head` action which is loading from [wp_head() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) doesn't have any argument. So, in the second snippet, you don't have any `$order_id` variable.

If you want to get order in `head` section, you may need to use WooCommerce functions to get the order and then print it as javascript in `head`.

Example:

```
function tracking_in_head() {
// Get needed data here.
$all_orders = wc_get_orders();
// Check https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order.html to see WC order functions.
?>
    <script>
        console.log( 'order_id: <?php echo $order_id; ?>' );
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'tracking_in_head' );
```